# Class relationship, Table reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

### I would like to ask a little help from you guys in C# MVC and SQL. Here is my problem. I have 2 tables Tbl_Master_Personnel_Info and Tbl_Ref_Gender

The first table have the following fields:

- PersonId
- LastName
- FirstName
- GenderId

The Second table have the following fiends:

- GenderId
- GenderName

I got this class PersonnelInfo and Gender

```
public class PersonnelInfo(){
public int PersonId {get; set;}
public string LastName {get; set;}
public string FirstName {get; set;}
public int GenderId {get; set;}
}

public class Gender(){
public int GenderId {get; set;}
public string GenderName {get; set;}
}
```

---

I already list the Personnel Info but I want the GenderId to be display as GenderName from the data of this table Tbl_Ref_Gender

```
Current result
------------------------------------------
1 | FirLastName | FirFirstName | FirMI | 10
2 | SecLastName | SecFirstName | SecMI | 20

How can I achieve this result.
------------------------------------------
1 | FirLastName | FirFirstName | FirMI | Male
2 | SecLastName | SecFirstName | SecMI | Female
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code that you can use .

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestConsole
{
    public class PersonnelInfo
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public int GenderId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    }

    public class Gender
    {
        [Key]
        public int GenderId { get; set; }
        public string GenderName { get; set; }
    }



    internal class Program
    {
        public TestConsoleDbContext MyDbContext { get; set; }

        public Program()
        {
            MyDbContext = new TestConsoleDbContext();
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var program = new Program();
            program.CreateData();

            var records = from p in program.MyDbContext.PersonnelInfos
                          select new { p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.Gender.GenderName };

            foreach (var r in records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1} Gender: {2}", r.FirstName, r.LastName, r.GenderName);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();


        }

        private void CreateData()
        {
            var record = new PersonnelInfo() { FirstName = "First Name 1", LastName = "Last Name 1", GenderId = GetGenderIdbyName("male") };
            var record1 = new PersonnelInfo() { FirstName = "First Name 2", LastName = "Last Name 2", GenderId = GetGenderIdbyName("female") };

            MyDbContext.PersonnelInfos.Add(record);
            MyDbContext.PersonnelInfos.Add(record1);
            MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        private int GetGenderIdbyName(string genderName)
        {
            var genderRecord = (from g in MyDbContext.Genders
                                where g.GenderName.Equals(genderName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                select g).FirstOrDefault();

            var genderId = 0;


            if (genderRecord == null)
            {
                var gender = new Gender() { GenderName = genderName };

                MyDbContext.Genders.Add(gender);
                MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
                genderId = gender.GenderId;

            }
            else
            {
                genderId = genderRecord.GenderId;
            }

            return genderId;

        }
    }
}
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace TestConsole
{
    internal class TestConsoleDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public IDbSet<PersonnelInfo> PersonnelInfos { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses sir.
After changing my class and running the application I got this error message **bold**The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.**bold** This is my code in my View @m.Tbl_Ref_Gender.Name

Comment: @AinneAvila Please see my response above.

Comment: Hi sir,
Just a followup question. 
I instantiate PersonnelInfo 

`code`
var dbPersonnelInfo = new List<PersonnelInfo>();

PersonnelInfo p = new PersonnelInfo();
p.CourseId = r.CourseId;
p.Batch = r.Batch;
p.LastName = r.LastName;
p.FirstName = r.FirstName;
p.MiddleName = r.MiddleName;
//This line is my problem.
// I dont know how to set the Gender name
//Since the datatype of GenderId is int
//and I setting the value to string
p.GenderId = r.Name;
dbPersonnelInfo.Add(p);
`code`
Sorry for making trouble.

Thank you very much

Comment: @AinneAvila You don't have to do that at all system will look after for it. once you have inserted then try to read as p.Gender.Name you will find the name on the basis of GenderId that is the beauty of ORM. Do make sure that in your this line defined. 
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }

Comment: @AinneAvila try running the code that I have provided you above.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a join on the two tables on the key GenderId in the following way.

```
IQueriable result = 
    from p in personnelList
    join g in GenderLIst on p.GenderId=g.GenderId
    select new 
    {
        PersonId = p.PersonId,
        FullName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
        GenderId = p.GenderId,
        GenderName = g.GenderName
    };
 }
```